# How to convert HTML datetime-local format to postgresql timestamp without time zone format

Tags: php, html, postgresql, datetime-format

I have to search some data from postgresql database using date limit. I am collecting  the dates through  HTML/PhP form using `datetime-local format` for date input field.

In the `postgresql`, the type of date field is `timestamp without time zone format` and the stored date values in it are like `2018-10-25 12:11:30`

Since the format of html form collected dates are different than postgresql date, I am not able to run the query.

How can I convert HTML datetime-local format to postgresql timestamp format as I put above.

**Here is code of my html form:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
 <label for="validationCustom01">Start Date</label>
 <input type="datetime-local" name="start_date" id="start_date" placeholder="insert start date" value="">
 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
  <label for="validationCustom01">End Date</label>
  <input type="datetime-local"name="end_date" id="end_date" placeholder="insert end date" value="">
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST["submit19"])){

   $meas_dev_id = $_POST["meas_dev_id"];
   $start_date = $_POST["start_date"];
   $end_date = $_POST["end_date"];

     try {
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, date_time, value1,   temperature FROM measurements where id = $meas_dev_id AND date_time >= $start_date AND date_time < $end_date LIMIT 10");
          $stmt->execute();

          $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           foreach(new TableRows(new  RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {       
            echo $v;
              }
                }
                 catch(PDOException $e) {
                  // echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                   exit('<b>Catched exception at line '. $e->getLine() .' (code : '. $e->getCode() .') :</b> '. $e->getMessage());
                }

?>
```

Comment: before you run your `try` you can reformat your date accordingly. What format is your `$_POST['start_date']` currently?

Comment: something like `$newStartDateFormat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_date));`

Comment: @Stender: it's in '2018-10-25T12:00' format

Comment: then the above code will work fine

Comment: you can even do this, so you don't need to change your sql : `$start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_date));`

Comment: created a playground for you : https://www.tehplayground.com/QeyWmRx4VQH2HZ6B

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much :)
Its working fine. There were syntax error/exception raised that I was correcting. I need to put  $newStartDateFormat in the query in quotes like '$newStartDateFormat' than it starts working. Thank you again for the kind help !!

Comment: I will check your later comments & playground now.